# Validation pattern for date not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I am having two textboxes like this :

```
<input class="searchDateFrom" pattern="((19|20)[0-9]{2})[\- \/.](0[1-9]|1[012])[\- \/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]))" title="Invalid Date" type="text" placeholder="Search From" id="searchDateFrom"></input>
<input class="searchDateTo" type="text" placeholder="Search To" id="searchDateTo"></input>
<input class="Datesubmit" type="button" value="Search" id="Datesubmit"></input>
```

But the pattern yyyy/mm/dd is not working an it is accepting invalid date also.Please help

Also how to restrict that searchDateTo is greater than the searchDateFrom.Please help

Answer (score 0):

Data validation in javascript is always complicate, and with regular expression is hard to take care about differnt months lenght, leap years and cultures.

You could make all simplier by introducing [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). With this tiny library you can validate date without worry abot dates, months length, leap years.